# Xamarin.Forms - How to use one instance of class when using Appshell routing?

Tags: xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, instance

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and have been following a guide where I use a plugin for video calling.

In the example they are not using AppShell but other type of navigation.

**In the iOS project appdelegate.cs they do this:**

```
    try {
            LoadApplication(new App(VidyoController.GetInstance()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.GetInstance().Log(e.Message);
        }
```

**Then in the app.xaml.cs they do this in order to get the videocontroller instance to the appropriate view:**

```
        public App(IVidyoController vidyoController)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mVidyoController = vidyoController;

        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(vidyoController);
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(homePage);
    }
```

I am now wondering how do I get the instance from the appdelegate to my view using AppShell routing?

**I started writing something like this:**

```
        public App(IVidyoController vidyoController)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mVidyoController = vidyoController;

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
```

But I really have no clue what to do next. The videoController is not going to be used on the first page in the application.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not use the appshell to pass the videocontroller instance to the other page. But you can define the videocontroller in the other page.

Second, if you want the videocontroller automatically start you can use the `OnAppearing()` method and write the code.